# transform jsonb with arbitrary keys

Tags: postgresql

I need to transform json objects with arbitrary keys, and integer values like so

`{"a":1, "sql":5}` → `{"a":{"f":1},"sql":{"f":5}}`.

I can't figure out the correct postgres jsonb methods. I've set up this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/toGP1HVYw6oSHH2W5RSLyd/1) to make it easy to interact.

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and [`jsonb_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) in a subquery:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, jsonb_build_object('f', value))
  FROM jsonb_each(f)
) AS transformed
FROM test
```

<sup>([updated fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/toGP1HVYw6oSHH2W5RSLyd/2))</sup>

Without a subquery, you can also directly aggregate when fetching only a single row or when grouping by a row identifier:

```
SELECT id, jsonb_object_agg(key, jsonb_build_object('f', value)) AS transformed
FROM test, jsonb_each(f)
GROUP BY id
```

<sup>([adjusted fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/toGP1HVYw6oSHH2W5RSLyd/3))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(j.key, jsonb_build_object('f', j.val))
  FROM ( VALUES
         ( 1, '{ "a": 1, "sql": 5 }'::jsonb )
       , ( 2, '{ "b": "test", "lqs": false }'::jsonb )
       ) t(id, jsonb_column)
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(t.jsonb_column) j(key, val)
 GROUP BY t.id
;
```

Returns

| jsonb_object_agg |
| --- |
| {"a": {"f": 1}, "sql": {"f": 5}} |
| {"b": {"f": "test"}, "lqs": {"f": false}} |